# AWS: Two Listeners in Network Load Balancers results in long loading times

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

**SETUP:**

I use Amazon Web Services for the backend services.

The computing services are hosted as FARGATE-Services in ECS.

To reach these Services, I use a Network Load Balancer (NLB).

In front of the NLB there is a REST API of API Gateway. This REST API is connected to the NLB via a Private Link. The API has to be a REST API (not a http-API). Thus, I can only connect a NLB and no Application Load Balancer.

---

**DESIRED FUNCTION:**

I want to reach two different services using the same NLB. To do this, I added two Listeners to the NLB, each listening to its own port and routing to a unique target group. This target group contains the desired service:

- Listener A | PORT 3000 | TARGET GROUP A | SERVICE A
- Listener B | PORT 4000 | TARGET GROUP B | SERVICE B

Now, when I call the load balancer DNS (or the API Gateway endpoint which has a proxy to this NLB) on port 3000 I want to reach service A. And when I call it on port 4000 I want to reach service B.

---

**PROBLEM:**

If I use the described setup to with the two Listeners, I can reach both Services via the ports but loading times increase to 2+ minutes (previous only few ms).

---

**REMARKS:**

1. The problem does not arise from the Fargate Services or the ECS setup as I tested these isolated.
2. The problem occurs with every ports I tried for the Listeners.
3. I know that a Application Load Balancer can be used to receive the desired function but since I have to use a REST API Gateway this is not an option.

Comment: Can you provide settings for the listeners and target groups?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem but using RDS
one listener is targeting writer instance and the other is targeting read replicas.
I'm also connecting to it from other AWS accounts using AWS Private Link. 
It used to work when I had only one listener but after adding I got the same results. Lambda functions taking ms before started taking more than 2 minutes

Comment: I'm having a similar issue! We had an NLB with one listener pointing to one ECS fargate service with 4 ports. Split it out into 4 listeners + 4 services and now connections time out or take minutes. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: same issue here. adding more listeners results in high latency.